# Passed parameters without being encrypted

Tags: django, security, parameter-passing

i'm using django to manage a website where ids like post id, user id are passed in clear.
For example i can have /posts/1, /posts/2/

Even if i check if current user can read the related post, is it really secure to pass parameters like that or should i do something like /posts/lkjfekj87Dokdz98/ which corresponds to /posts/1/ for example ?

Example of a detail view called with /post/1/

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(generic.DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if context['post'] not in self.request.user.allowed_post:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return context
```

Comment: I wouldn't be passing primary keys though the querystring, especially not the user id.

Comment: If you're filtering views by only the ones they can see, plus the view is already protected by @login_required, you can get the user id from the session instead of passing it in.

Comment: please re-read i'm not asking about the USER id parameter but a potentiel id like car, house, book, post etc. in general should we encrypt get parameters ?

Comment: You said "...like post id, *user id* are passed in clear..."

Comment: As long as you're only allowing the correct user to edit each record, you're probably alright. You'll want to run your app over https as well.

Comment: ok scuse me, i meaned user list corresponding to an organisation for example. user was a bad example :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36743/discussion-between-brandon-and-gorjuce)

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer. This technique is named obfuscations. It can be used for example with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-unfriendly